# Cordova/phonegap plugin compatibility questions - org.chromium.socket / org.chromium.notifications

Tags: javascript, android, plugins, cordova, compatibility

I'm looking to revamp an app of mine that uses notifications and websockets, as of the latest version (3.x) Cordova/Phonegap now use a plugin repositiory (think npmjs.org).

The only websocket (that I need compatibility with older android devices) and notification plugins (same as before, but also for abstraction) are the org.chromium.socket/notification ones.

I cannot find any documentaion about how far back they are compatible/do they require chrome to be installed on the users device.

Any ideas girls & guys?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't require Chrome, org.chromium.socket is a plugin like any other!

Docs: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket